# Call func at memory address

Tags: go

I have a map with a struct as key and a func as value, I would like to call the func when I retrieve the value for a given key

```
map[struct]func

map[
    {contact %!s(int=1)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7b50) 
    {services/basket %!s(int=2)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7ad0) 
    {categories %!s(int=1)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7ae0) 
    {categories/{category} %!s(int=2)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7af0)
    {categories/{category}/{product} %!s(int=3)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7b00) 
    {basket %!s(int=1)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7b10) 
    {checkout %!s(int=1)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7b40) 
    {sitemap %!s(int=1)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7b30) 
    {services/order %!s(int=2)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7ac0) 
    {services/image %!s(int=2)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7b20) 
    {/ %!s(int=1)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7a00)
]

c := RouteMap[struct]
```

If I `fmt.Printf("%s", c)` I get the memory address, how do I invoke the func at the address?

I have tried c() but that gives a runtime error:

```
%s
0x4c7b10%s
<nil>panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x4c76f4]

goroutine 5 [running]:
main.RequestHandler(0x577ce0, 0xc042004018)
        C:/Users/mon/Desktop/server.go:91 +0x684
created by main.main
        C:/Users/mon/Desktop/server.go:41 +0x2a0
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var RouteMap = make(map[PathIdentifier]Controller)

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    MapRoute("/", HomeController)
    MapRoute("categories", CategoriesController)
    MapRoute("categories/{category}", CategoryController)
    MapRoute("categories/{category}/{product}", CategoryProductController)
    MapRoute("basket", BasketController)

    MapRoute("checkout", CheckoutController)
    MapRoute("sitemap", SitemapController)
    MapRoute("contact", ContactController)

    MapRoute("services/order", OrderServiceController)
    MapRoute("services/basket", BasketServiceController)
    MapRoute("services/image", ImageServiceController)

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", RouteMap)

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
        go RequestHandler(conn)
    }
}

// ----------------------- Request & Response ---------------------------

func ParseQueryString() {}

func ParsePostData() {}

func ResponseHeaders() {}

func ParseRequestHeaders() {}

func RequestHandler(conn net.Conn) {
CrLf := "\r\n"
Terminator := CrLf + CrLf

defer func() {
    //fmt.Println("Closing connection...")
    conn.Close()
}()

timeoutDuration := 10 * time.Second
bufReader := bufio.NewReader(conn)

conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(timeoutDuration))

requestBytes, err := bufReader.ReadBytes('\n')
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

requestTokens := bytes.Split(requestBytes, []byte(" "))

requestMethod := string(requestTokens[0])
requestPath := string(requestTokens[1])
//requestHTTPVersion := string(requestTokens[2])

if requestMethod == "GET" {
    // Parse path
    pathTokens := strings.Split(requestPath, "/")
    segments := len(pathTokens)

    key := PathIdentifier{path: "categories/{category}/{product}", segments: (segments - 1)}
    c := RouteMap[key]

    fmt.Print("%s\n", c)

}

    document := []byte("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CrLf + "Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT" + CrLf + "Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT" + CrLf + "Content-Length: 49" + CrLf + "Content-Type: text/html" + CrLf + "Connection: Closed" + Terminator + "<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>" + Terminator)

    conn.Write(document)
}

// ----------------------------- Controller -----------------------------

type Controller func()

type PathIdentifier struct {
    path     string
    segments int
}

func MapRoute(view string, controller Controller) {
    if controller != nil {

        if view != "/" {
            pathTokens := strings.Split(view, "/")

            key := PathIdentifier{path: view, segments: len(pathTokens)}
            RouteMap[key] = controller
            return
        }

        key := PathIdentifier{path: view, segments: 1}
        RouteMap[key] = controller
    }
}

func HomeController() {
    fmt.Print("Invoking the HomeController.\n")
}

func OrderServiceController() {

}

func BasketServiceController() {

}

func CategoriesController() {

}

func CategoryController() {

}

func CategoryProductsController() {

}

func CategoryProductController() {

}

func BasketController() {

}

func ImageServiceController() {

}

func SitemapController() {

}

func CheckoutController() {

}

func ContactController() {

}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/t2oIjLJ34b

Comment: You example works: https://play.golang.org/p/uRd9kd4ud1 please show an example that reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: I have updated the example

Comment: Btw I'm not sure if it's missing only from the example, but you should use "comma ok" idiom to check that the request path has a registered controller in the `RouteMap`. E.g. `if c, ok := RouteMap[key]; !ok { ...` if `ok` is `false` that means that no controller is registered for that key. https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps

Comment: In the updated example, inside `RequestHandler` you're constructing the key with a hardcoded path (`categories/{category}/{product}`) and a computed segment count from the actual request path (`segments - 1`).. how's that supposed to match any key? Only by luck are you actually gonna get a match... Seems to me the `RouteMap` should work fine, on the other hand, the logic in your `RequestHandler` seems off.

Comment: The part with the hardcoded key is just for debugging/development, thats af course goint to be dynamic, what seems off?

Comment: Then you should hardocde the segment count as well

Comment: The URL i use to connect to the program is going to get me a segment count of 3, so thats not a problem.

Comment: For better debugging, log the key you're using to retrieve the controller and also the contents of the RouteMap, and then look if that key is actually in the map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141453/discussion-between-user1359448-and-mkopriva).

Comment: The chat seems to be broken, I know the key is present in the map e.g. {categories/{category}/{product} %!s(int=3)}:%!s(main.Controller=0x4c7b00) I get the correct memory address back, i just cant invoke the function.

Comment: Can you mention what path you are using that gets you the 3 segments count? I would like to test your code on my machine.

Comment: Btw your code works fine for me, here is the code i ran: https://play.golang.org/p/M04C20-krd (i've edited only the log and added a call to `c`). And here you can see it **not** crashing when calling `c`: http://imgur.com/EzoUDNk.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/categories/development-boards/arm-cortex-m0-minimal

Comment: If you run the provided example code, as opposed to your real code, does it crash too when calling `c`? I'm able to run it just fine even with your path (`/categories/development-boards/arm-cortex-m0-minimal`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need to call it "by address". When you call by passing it as a variable, compiler does this for you "under-the-hood". Takes its address and calls it.

If you wish some level of indirection, you can make:

```
M := map[string]func()
M["function 1"] = F
// and then call them from map like 
M["function 1"]()
```